# Install Oracle 12c on Oracle Linux 6.7 port in use

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, installation, listener

I have attempted to install Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 on Oracle Linux 6.7 multiple times without success.  I have installed the database software only with the configuration assistant and am attempting to configure the listener with the net configuration assistant (netca).  I go through the steps and the netca hangs and eventually fails on the standard port saying it is in use by another process.  I have checked the ports (`sudo ss -tulw`) and know this is not true.  I have searched and have seen similar problems that seem to be associated with either the `.bash_profile` or `/etc/hosts` files not being set correctly.  I have checked both of those files and do not see any issue, but I am new to setting up a DB so please see below for any possible errors:

### /etc/hosts

```
#127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost.localdomain localhost
192.168.1.77 ggsrv1.localdomain ggsrv1
192.168.1.78 ggsrv2.localdomain ggsrv2
```

I am attempting to set up 2 databases to try out Oracle GoldenGate. so ggsrv1 is the current database I am trying to install and ggsrv2 is the other database I hope to install, an a second vm.

### .bash_profile

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH

export TMP=/tmp
export TMPDIR=$TMP
export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=ggsrv1.localdomain
export ORACLE_UNQNAME=db1
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/12.1.0.2/db_1
export ORACLE_SID=db1
export PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
export CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib
```

I am able to start up dbca and netca from the terminal so I feel the paths are set correctly.  Is there something above that I am not seeing or could there be another possible issue?

### `lsnrctl start` output

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 04-SEP-2019 07:44:18

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ggsrv1/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ggsrv1.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00505: Operation timed out
```

the contents of /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ggsrv1/listener/alert/log.xml show that it is listening on the post in /etc/hosts.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you

## Edit

I did not have a `listener.ora` file so I created one that looked like the below.

```
LISTENER=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS_LIST=
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ggsrv1.localdomain)(PORT=1521))
      ))

 SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = db1)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1)
    )
)
```

#### I then ran the below with the following output:

```
[oracle@ggsrv1 admin]$ lsnrctl start LISTENER

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 05-SEP-2019 10:24:18

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ggsrv1/listener/alert/log.xml
TNS-01150: The address of the specified listener name is incorrect

Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...
```

I do not have a `sqlnet.ora` file, and do not know what it is, but I will investigate now.

## Edit 2

After reading about the files located in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` it seems like I do not need these if I accept the system defaults correct?

I have added a `listener.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` files anyways, but I still cannot start the listener:

`TNS-01150: The address of the specified listener name is incorrect`

the contents of my tnsnames.ora file:

```
db1 = (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ggsrv1.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = db1)
    )
  )
```

### `ifconfig` output

```
  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:D0:AE:EC  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fed0:aeec/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:44741 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32187 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30928622 (29.4 MiB)  TX bytes:5468976 (5.2 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:480 (480.0 b)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 b)
```

Comment: Forget netca. `lsnrctl start`. If it works, it is done. If it does not, at least it displays the address it is trying to use.

Comment: When you say you’re trying to set up 2 databases what do you mean? 2 different hosts with a database on each, or 1 host (with 2 IP addresses and names) with 2 databases on?

Comment: @BalazsPapp I added the the output from `lsnrctl start` above.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ I am trying to set up 2 different hosts with a database on each.  I have 2 different vm's set up with virtualbox.

Comment: @JeffTilton are you able to ping 192.168.1.77 ggsrv1.localdomain ggsrv1
192.168.1.78 ggsrv2.localdomain ggsrv2   both as IP and name?

Comment: @JeffTilton can you also provide contents of listener.ora and sqlnet.ora?

Comment: @VCarstein I updated the summary above.  I do not have a sqlnet.ora file. I do not have a sqlnet.ora file.  It just hangs when I ping either ggsrv1 or ggsrv2.  Same thing when I try to ping from ggsrv2.

Comment: @VCarstein I seem to only be able to ping 192.168.1.001 all other IP addresses hang.  Networking is out of my element, but I thought I could choose any address 192.168.1.xxx.  Is this not correct?

Comment: @Kumar the output is shown above can you explain what I should look for here? thanks

Comment: @JeffTilton I think the main issue here is the network setup.  You need to be able to successfully ping the IP or the fully qualified name.  I also think the listener is malformed.  At this stage you can try (in the listener.ora file)  <br/>  1. replacing host=ggsrv1.localdomain to host=localhost  2. remove the whole SID_LIST_LISTENER block  3. rewrite the LISTENER= to :  LISTENER =  
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =  
    (DESCRIPTION =  
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))  
    )  
  )  
4. start the listener using `lsnrctl start listener`

Comment: Do you *have* to stick with Oracle Linux?  When I was forced to use this, it was basically a locked down version of Red Hat that didn't allow for 3rd party drivers, etc.  When we finally moved away form it, many of the system headaches went away.  I'm not saying this is your answer, but if it's option, I suggest you explore it.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener I am only using this setup to follow along a course on Oracle GoldenGate that my work is moving towards replacing Oracle Streams.  So I guess I do not *have* to stick with Oracle Linux, although I do not know if that will allow me to follow along or not.  We use Solaris at work so I could try that route.  I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: @VCarstein any idea why I can only ping 192.168.1.1?  Is that something I messed up in the VM setup? Is there a setting somewhere?  I will obviously start exploring myself as well.  Thanks for getting me to this point in understanding the problem.

Comment: @VCarstein I think I figured it out, I just need to find some time to try it out.  You are right about the networking.  I am a programmer and mainly understand networking as a series of tubes so this process, although frustrating has given me a lot of info.  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEj42l4otNY) explained a lot if anyone else runs in to the same issue.